# How to run array of Invoke-SshCommand in PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, ssh

I would like to run a couple of SSH commands using PowerShell `Invoke-SshCommand`. I know how to use it, but when I want to run more of them like for example `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install` and `cd..` they do not wait for each other and it causes errors. Is there any way of getting the information whether one command was finished so I could run next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't invoke the commands separately. Daisy-chain the commands with semicolons and invoke the entire list in a single statement:

```
$cmds = 'sudo apt-get update', 'sudo apt-get install', 'cd ..'
Invoke-SshCommand -Command ($cmds -join ';')
```